# Need help with pandoc filter

Tags: overleaf, pandoc

I'm trying convert my latex document to word using pandoc. In my latex document i have written `$\left(a;b\right)_{\infty}$ using $\p(a;b)$` by defining new command

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\p}{r()}{
  \ensuremath{\left(#1\right)_{\infty}}
}.
```

Now the pandoc not able to convert the this part of latex to word. Trying to use custom filter.lua

```
  if elem.t == 'RawInline' and elem.format:match('tex') then
    local content = elem.text
    local new_content = content:gsub('\\\\p{([^}]*)}', function(param)
      return '\\ensuremath{\\left(' .. param .. '\\right)_{\\infty}}'
    end)
    return pandoc.RawInline('tex', new_content)
  end
end
```

the code is not working. Help me writing the custom filter which converts the above macro. (I don't  have much background in creating custom filters.) Thank you n advance

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Why would you want to write `\left(a;b\right)` instead of just `(a;b)`?

Comment: It is not just $(a;b)$. I work in the area of q-series where we frequently use q-Pochammer symbol (a;b)_{\infinity}. So i use this LaTex macro.